# What's the purpose of glib's g_atomic_int_get?

Tags: c, glib

glib a provides [`g_atomic_int_get`](https://git.gnome.org/browse/glib/tree/glib/gatomic.c?h=2.52.0#n537) function to atomically read a standard C `int` type. Isn't reading 32-bit integers from memory into registers not already guaranteed to be an atomic operation by the processor (e.g. `mov <reg32>, <mem>`)?

If yes, then what's the purpose of glib's `g_atomic_int_get` function?

Comment: `Isn't ... already guaranteed to be an atomic operation by the processor?` Well, _what_ processor? I'm sure there are some where it is, and some where it isn't.

Comment: Also int might not be 32 bit, neither the register.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some processors allow reading unaligned data, but that may take more than a single cycle. I.e. it's no longer atomic. On others it might not be an atomic operation at all to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

The x86 `mov` instruction is not always atomic, either: it is [non-atomic if the addresses involved are not naturally aligned](http://preshing.com/20130618/atomic-vs-non-atomic-operations/#non-atomic-cpu-instructions).

Even if it were always atomic, it is not a [memory barrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier), which means the compiler is free to reorder the instruction with reference to other instructions nearby; and the processor is free to reorder the instruction with reference to other instructions in the instruction stream at runtime.

Unless you are writing code targeting only a single platform (and are sure that code will never need to be ported to another platform), you must always use explicit atomic instructions if you want atomic guarantees.